# Cannot remove bootstrap button border

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a custom bootstrap button and I cannot remove its border after click. I was able to change its background color but there is an insistent blue border boring me.

I click on it, it opens a modal window and after closing the modal the border is still there until I click on another part of the page even if I change values in `:active` and `:focus`.

[image]

**html**:

```
<button id="openPopup" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg text-uppercase" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    some text here
</button>
```

**css**:

```
#openPopup {
  padding: 20px 30px;
  background-color: #a2238e;
  border-color: #a2238e;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #999;
  white-space: normal;
  font-size: smaller;
  letter-spacing: 0.2px;
}

#openPopup:hover, #openPopup:active, #openPopup:focus {
  background-color: #912284 !important;
  border-color: #912284 !important;
}
```

Comment: You are probably looking for `outline`, not `border`. However, consider this: [Give Your Site Some Focus! Tips for Designing Useful and Usable Focus Indicators](https://www.deque.com/blog/give-site-focus-tips-designing-usable-focus-indicators/)

Comment: Look up in dev tools what css rule is doing blue border and change it there or figure out more specific selector and/or use `!important` to override it

Comment: I just test it and their is no blue border

Comment: @FelixKling Perfect man! `outline` did the trick. Post an answer for me to close the question if you want. Thanks!

Comment: could you post an answer with outline?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
#openPopup:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

or

```
#openPopup:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 21):

On Bootstrap 4.5.0 you can try

```
<button class="btn btn-primary shadow-none">ADD TEXT HERE</button>
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 14):

### Try This

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-link">Link</button>
```

[Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/)

Answer (score 9):

for Bootstrap 4:

Use can use `border-0` utility class to remove border from elements like buttons:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary border-0">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

**Try this:**

just add shadow-none class next to the btn-primary class

```
<button class="btn btn-primary shadow-none>some text</button>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer is another copy of Fabio Duarte answer!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
#openPopup { outline:none; border-style: none; }

#openPopup:hover, #openPopup:active, #openPopup:focus { outline: none; border-style: none; }
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me on Bootstrap 4.6.0

```
#openPopup {
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Comment: This works on Bootstrap 5 as well. Excellent answer. If you are specifically trying to remove an unwanted border which as added when a button is clicked in bootstrap, box-shadow: none is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the border on :focus and :active

```
#openPopup:active, #openPopup:focus { 
   border-style: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on bootstrap 5.

```
style="border-radius: 0em;"
```

Answer (score 0):

#openPopup add   `box-shadow: none;`
[like this](https://codepen.io/gulsenkeskin/pen/bGrWrQx)